# PySpark using s3a throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've a bunch of code that works perfectly with s3n, but when i try to switch to s3a I just get some sort of java.lang.IllegalArgumentException without a real pointer or hint as to what exactly is wrong.. would appreciate some suggestions for debugging! I'm on hadoop-aws-2.7.3 and aws-java-sdk-1.7.4 so I believe that should be fine

error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1aafd157ea37> in <module>
----> 1 schema_df = spark.read.json('s3a://udemy-stream-logs/cdn-access-raw/verizon/mp4-a.udemycdn.com/wpc_C9216_306_20200701_0C390000BFD7B55E_100.json_lines.gz')
      2 schema = schema_df.schema

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py in json(self, path, schema, primitivesAsString, prefersDecimal, allowComments, allowUnquotedFieldNames, allowSingleQuotes, allowNumericLeadingZero, allowBackslashEscapingAnyCharacter, mode, columnNameOfCorruptRecord, dateFormat, timestampFormat, multiLine, allowUnquotedControlChars, lineSep, samplingRatio, dropFieldIfAllNull, encoding, locale, pathGlobFilter, recursiveFileLookup)
    298             path = [path]
    299         if type(path) == list:
--> 300             return self._df(self._jreader.json(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    301         elif isinstance(path, RDD):
    302             def func(iterator):

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    126     def deco(*a, **kw):
    127         try:
--> 128             return f(*a, **kw)
    129         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    130             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.json.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1293)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1215)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.initialize(S3AFileSystem.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3303)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:297)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:477)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

my code:

```
conf = (SparkConf()
    .set('spark.executor.extraJavaOptions', '-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true')
    .set('spark.driver.extraJavaOptions', '-Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4=true')
    .set('spark.master', 'local[*]')
    .set('spark.driver.memory', '4g'))

scT = SparkContext(conf=conf)
scT.setSystemProperty('com.amazonaws.services.s3.enableV4', 'true')
scT.setLogLevel("INFO")

hadoopConf = scT._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3.buffer.dir', '/tmp/pyspark')

hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.awsAccessKeyId', 'key')
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.awsSecretAccessKey', 'secret')
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.endpoint', 's3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com')
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.multipart.size', '104857600')
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.impl', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem')
hadoopConf.set('fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider', 'org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.BasicAWSCredentialsProvider')

spark = SparkSession(scT)

df = spark.read.json('s3a://mybucket/something_something.json_lines.gz')
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the little detail that you have set the username and password *in the wrong properties for the s3a connector*, that stack trace implies its from thread pool construction. Presumably one of the parameters passed in (thread pool size, keep alive time. is somehow invalid. No obvious cue as to which specific option is provided by the JVM though.

My recommendation is to stop copying and pasting other stack overflow examples and look at [the s3a documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html). See what the options are for authentication and then for bounded and unbounded thread pools and make sure they're set

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you, and I figure out this was caused by the code you configure "fs.s3a.multipart.size". I removed it and the problem has gone. You could try it.